# SVD and transpose of a skinny matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Show: If $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ with $M\geq N$, 
then there exists a matrix $\mathbf{G}$ with orthonormal
rows so that $\mathbf{A}^T=\mathbf{G}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{G}$.

I'm pretty lost on this problem. I know that I'm going to have to use the SVD at some point in the proof though. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where did you come across this question?

Comment: i like the title of this question; pretty descriptive.

Comment: @vdesai it was homework problem of mine from a Numerical Analysis course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assume rank of matrix $A$ to be $N$.**

We can start with SVD, which provides the following decomposition: $$
A_{M\times N} = U_{M\times N} \Sigma_{N\times N} V^\top_{N\times N}.
$$
Then,
$$
A^\top = V\Sigma U^\top = VU^\top U \Sigma V^\top V U^\top = VU^\top A VU^\top.
$$
Pattern matching with $A^\top = GAG$, gives $G = VU^\top$.

Rows of $G$ are orthonormal is equivalent to $G G^\top = I_{N\times N}$. 
$$
GG^\top = VU^\top UV^\top = VV^\top = I_{N\times N}.
$$
The last equality is because $V$ is a square matrix and $V^\top V = I$ and therefore $V^{-1} = V^\top$.

Comment: looks like you forgot get rid of $ character at the end of a line. But besides that typo, this is delightfully simple. Thanks!

Comment: How do we know that the rows of G are orthonormal? We know that the columns of V are orthonormal, and the rows of U^T are orthnormal, but does that imply that G has orthonormal rows?

Comment: @Drew good question. I have revised the answer. I think we need the assumption that $A$ is full column rank.